# How to add Firebase Crashlytics in kotlin-only module?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, multi-module

I have a multi-module Android project. The Modules are: "app", "core", "auth", "coreAndroid", and various feature modules. I am trying to add Firebase Crashlytics to the "core" module that is kotlin-only, so that I can create a function like:

```
fun cLog(msg: String?){
     FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(msg)
}
```

which will be accessed by all kotlin-only modules (like networking) to log error messages.

I have followed the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android) but I can get the FirebaseCrashlytics Instance only in Android Modules. The google-services.json file is in the "app" module. I have been trying various solutions from the web for 3 days now but nothing seems to work.

The way that I have [structured my gradle files](https://proandroiddev.com/intro-to-app-modularization-42411e4c421e) is that I have an android-library-build.gradle and a library-build.gradle file, each of which act as a common ground for for their respective android and kotlin-only modules.

These are my gradle files:

(app) build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version Kotlin.version //"1.6.10"
    kotlin("kapt")
    id ("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id ("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

...

dependencies {
...

    implementation (platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0"))
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx")
}
```

(project) build.gradle.kts

```
buildscript {
    val kotlin_version by extra("1.8.0")
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        ...

        // Dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")

        // Dependency for the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.4")

    }
}
```

android-library-build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

...

dependencies {
...

    implementation (platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0"))
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx")
}
```

library-build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'


dependencies{

...
    implementation (platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0"))
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx")
}

apply {
    plugin("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    plugin("com.google.gms.google-services")
}
```

(core) build.gradle.kts

```
apply {
    from("$rootDir/library-build.gradle")
}

plugins {
    kotlin(KotlinPlugins.serialization) version Kotlin.version
}



dependencies {
    ...
}
```

I have also tried:

- to implement directly the dependencies and the plugins in the core build.gradle.kts file without success (with the platform implementation, and with the separate dependencies implementation).
- to copy/paste the google-services.gson file in the core module
- to [use Firebase on Android without the google-services plugin](https://medium.com/@samstern_58566/how-to-use-firebase-on-android-without-the-google-services-plugin-93ecc7dc6c4) meaning that I copy/pasted the generated strings from app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/main/values/values.xml to the strings.xml file of app module, and deleted the gson file with the relevant plugins, and still didn't work.

I really can't figure it out. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: `com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx` depends on `com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics`, which depends on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks`, which is part of Play Services and only exists on Android.

Comment: So there isn't a way to use crashlytics in Kotlin modules? What if you get a crash in a network call using Ktor?

Comment: I do not know if Crashlytics supports plain JVM projects -- I have never looked. If they do, presumably it is via some different dependency. Or, consider alternative services, such as [Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments of @CommonsWare, it seems that its not possible to use directly the crashlytics library in a kotlin-only module.

I have found another way using an Interface in the koltin-only "core" module, and its implementation in the "app" module that has access to the crashlytics libraries.

Here is a simple example:

"core" module:

```
interface CrashlyticsService {
    fun cLog(message: String?)
}
```

"app" module:

```
class FirebaseCrashlyticsService : CrashlyticsService {

    override fun cLog(message: String?){
        message?.let {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(it)
            }
    }

}
```

And then, wherever I want to use the cLog function in other modules that depend on "core" i just inject it in the constructor of the Class, i.e. :

```
class NetworkingServiceImpl(
    private val httpClient: HttpClient,
    private val crashlyticsService: CrashlyticsService
) : NetworkingService {


    override suspend fun downloadVideo(videoUrl: String): ByteArray {
        crashlyticsService.cLog("This is a crash test message")
        return httpClient.get(videoUrl).body()
    }

}
```